# Openlayers 3 "rendering hardware-accelerated" of Chrome disable personal tiles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, openlayers-3

I maked personal tiles for a WEB Gis and I use cartographic motor OpenLayers3. I've any problem for see tiles with Mozilla or IE but with Google Chrome I've white tiles instead of real tiles in cause of the "rendering hardware-accelerated" (If I disable this parameter I can see all my tiles).

Like that :
[image]

How can I do for see my tiles with the "rendering hardware-accelerated" ? (For example the OSM tiles don't have this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably you reproject your local tiles while OSM are not reprojected. Thats why you have the rendering fail only on your local tiles. This is a known issue [#5236](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5236) and it seems it has to do with performance regression of chrome. The bug has been reported to chrome.

In the meantime you either switch to 3.13 version or disable the hardware accelaration. A last option is to serve you tiles unreprojected (dont do any client reprojection) or create your tiles using your map projection (I guess this is 3857) so no client reprojection shall take place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer pavlos, but my tiles were created with the EPSG of OSM, and you're right it's the PESG 3857

Comment: can you try with version 3.13 to see if that fixes the problem. Just to let us know. You may also check this issue(https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5305) which might be your case

Comment: Yes it work with version 13.x and version 14.0 and 14.1 but from version 14.2 the problem appeared !

Comment: ok thanks for that. You may also provide this info to the issue (github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5305) so give some feedback to the people behind ol3 dev.